# How to install Valorant on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, wine, games

I need help on how to install Valorant. I installed it and when it had finished I opened it, but it didn't work.

I'm using wine 5.0.

Is there any way to get it running?

---

Editor's note: The question was later changed to ask how to install Epic Games launcher, and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346811/527764) was accepted. A new question should have been asked instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, Epic Games launcher can be downloaded through Lutris.

Please see [here](https://lutris.net/downloads/) for that (Make sure to download Wine first).

After installing it, search up Fortnite. Installing Fortnite really just installs the Epic Games Launcher. After that, you gain access to both Lutris and Epic Games Launcher, but be careful. Most games on their don't support Linux and will just reject you.

Honestly, save yourself the trouble and dual-boot with Windows, most of Epic's good games don't support Linux, Wine or VM's.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Riot Games' anti-cheat system is not compatible with Wine, as well as the installer tends to crash in virtual environments. So at the moment, no it's not possible.

Source: [Is Valorant available on Linux?](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/faqs/649952-valorant-linux-support-availability)